# Making a Button that outputs a greeting

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kinda new to programming and need help with integrating javascript and html. I am trying to make an html page that has a name input section and a submit button to give a greeting from the function in a javascript file. I've tried using the form and input tags and was wondering how i output to the html page.

Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test button</title>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="testbutton" action="" method="GET">Enter your name</form>
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" value="">
    <input type="button" name="button"  value="click" onclick="greetings(this.form)" id="">
    <h1></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function greeting(a) {
    return "Hello " + a + ", nice to meet you"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```js
function alpha(){
  var str=document.getElementById('input1').value;
  str ===""? str = "Maria":null;
  console.log(str);
  alert(greeting(str));
}


function greeting(a) {
    return "Hello " + a + ", nice to meet you"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<button onclick="alpha()" value="Maria">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Yes thank you! could you explain the use of the "alpha" function please?

Comment: Instead of 2, I could have added all code in 1 function only, but I thought you anyways wanted `function greeting()` to return a value. So, I used two functions, instead you could have written directly `alert("Hello " + a + ", nice to meet you")` directly in alpha() only, instead of calling `greeting()` and could then delete the 2nd function - greeting().

Answer (score 2):

Key APIs used:

- [*element*.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [*element*.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [*element*.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

See HTML and JavaScript comments:

```js
// This is what is in script.js

// Don't use inline event attributes like onclick.
// Keep JavaScript out of your HTML.
// Set up your events in JavaScript
document.querySelector("input[type='button']").addEventListener("click", greeting);

// Get references to the elements you'll need:
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let output = document.querySelector("h1");

function greeting() {
    // Place your output in an existing HTML element
    output.textContent = "Hello " + input.value + ", nice to meet you";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test button</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- No need for a <form> if you're not submitting data anywhere. -->
    Enter your name
    <!-- No need to set value="", that's the default.
         No need to set type="text", that's also the default.
         And no need to set name="..." if you're not submitting data. -->
    <input>
    <input type="button" value="click">
    <h1></h1>
    
    <!-- Add your script references just before the closing
         body tag so that by the time the script is encountered
         all the HTML elements will have been parsed into memeory. -->
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```