# how to make a name based greeting alert in html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PpxS.png)

I want when I click the submit button, a pop up name-based greeting alert appears.

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: The similar question is already on stack overflow, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65239706/5852133

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are not a free coding site. You are expected to write your own code, and post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the particular problem you are having. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70843185/edit) to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like this maybe?

HTML element:

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

in your js file:

```
function myFunction() {
     alert("Hello my name is..")
}
```